# Spring request parameters UTF-8 support

Tags: java, spring

I need to apply a Filter to facilitate setting the request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") before first use of the request.getParameter(), otherwise my parameters are read as ISO_8859_1, setting it later does not work.

Unfortunately the 1st 'reading' filter is the Spring (4.3.13.RELEASE) Security 'CsrfFilter' & I'm unable to set a filter before it.

I'm using a minimal (no login required) spring security chain defined by:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler"/>        
</http>
```

The whole application works except for reading characters outside of ISO_8859_1, I need full UTF-8 support. Ive confirmed the network traffic is UTF. But is popping out of the request.getParameter() calls as ISO_8859_1.

My solution was to add a Spring GenericFilterBean as below.

```
<http>
    <custom-filter after="FIRST" ref="utf8Filter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="utf8Filter" class="my.SetRequestEncodingFilter"/>
```

But this generates a run time startup exception.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute

I'm unable to find a security chain setup that allows inclusing of a filter (but needs to before the csf filter). 
I'm thinking this is really a CsrfFilter bug'et, but it shouldnt be compromising subsequent getParameter() usage - but I dont really want to go there.

I tried the following - same result

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="myFormAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
</beans:bean>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running Tomcat?

Comment: yes, running in tomcat container

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly give default character encoding to be used by application by giving following argument at run time of application:

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: started tomcat with this & unfortunately didnt translate to setting the request's parameters to UTF-8, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running Tomcat, you can just configure the input encoding in `server.xml` at the HTTP [Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) like this:

```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             URIEncoding="UTF-8"
             ... >
```

Comment: I saw that but suspected this related to the path parameters. So i dont know if it will work. As I use a tomcat7-maven-plugin for test, I tried various configs there to no avail - so didnt take the connector path further.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a WebApplicationInitializer seems to have resolved the issue without the need to worry about the servlet chain. I also didnt have to touch my web.xml.

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encoding-filter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
      encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
      encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
      encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");       
}
```